# how to skip top rows when importing csv to mysql workbench

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I'm attempting to import a csv file into mysql workbench but the top row is the title of the table and the next 2 rows are blank. Hows do I skip the top 3 rows and start importing at the column headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier to use LOAD DATA like below:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'MYFILENAME.CSV'
INTO TABLE `mytablename`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 3 LINES;
```